# Writing IWICBtmap to file - incorrect resolution

Tags: c++, image, winapi, direct2d, wic

I have the following code where I read an image (JPG for test), specify a clipping rectangle area and write the "clipped" area out to a file.

My test image is 320 x 240 pixels @ 300dpi. When I read it in all indications say that it is that size but when I write it out the result image is 102 x 76 and looking a the file properties I see no H/V resolution.

Now 320/102 = 3.1372   and 300/96 = 3.125 so is there something with screen resolution vs image?

This entire subject of writing out a IWICBitmap has been a boxing match from the beginning. Why is it this hard?

Thanks a bunch

```
IWICImagingFactory *pImageFactory = GfxAgent::WICImagingFactory::GetInstance().GetFactory();

   D2D1_SIZE_U sizeFrame = D2D1::SizeU(imageRect.Width(), imageRect.Height());

   CComPtr<IWICBitmap> pWICBitmap;
   hr = pImageFactory->CreateBitmap(imageRect.Width(), imageRect.Height(),
      GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA,
      WICBitmapCacheOnLoad,
      &pWICBitmap
      );

   D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES rtProps = D2D1::RenderTargetProperties();
   rtProps.pixelFormat = D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED);
   rtProps.type = D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_DEFAULT;
   rtProps.usage = D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_USAGE_NONE;

   // define the render target
   CComPtr<ID2D1RenderTarget> pRenderTarget = 0;
   hr = m_pDirect2dFactory->CreateWicBitmapRenderTarget(pWICBitmap, rtProps, &pRenderTarget);

   CComPtr<ID2D1Bitmap> imageS;
   hr = GfxAgent::ImageUtilities::LoadImageFromFile(pRenderTarget, m_imgPath, 0, 0, 0, &imageS, &resX, &resY);

   if (hr != S_OK)
   {
   }

   // get format of image we just read
   D2D1_PIXEL_FORMAT fmt = imageS->GetPixelFormat();

   CComPtr<ID2D1Bitmap> imageD;
   D2D1_SIZE_U bitmapPixelSize = D2D1::SizeU(imageRect.Width(), imageRect.Height());

   // create destination image of "clipped" source image
   hr = pRenderTarget->CreateBitmap(bitmapPixelSize, D2D1::BitmapProperties(
      D2D1::PixelFormat(fmt.format, fmt.alphaMode),
      (float)resX, (float)resY), &imageD);

   D2D1_POINT_2U topleft = D2D1::Point2U(0, 0);
   D2D1_RECT_U srcRect = D2D1::RectU(imageRect.left, imageRect.top, imageRect.right, imageRect.bottom);
   // get the "clipped" source
   hr = imageD->CopyFromBitmap(&topleft, imageS, &srcRect);

   if (hr != S_OK)
   {
   }

   CComPtr<IWICBitmapEncoder> pEncoder;
   CComPtr<IWICBitmapFrameEncode> pFrame;
   CComPtr<IWICStream> pStream;

   WICPixelFormatGUID format = GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA;

   // draw the "clipped" image into the render target (WIC image)
   if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
      pRenderTarget->BeginDraw();
      pRenderTarget->Clear();
      pRenderTarget->DrawBitmap(imageD);
      hr = pRenderTarget->EndDraw();
   }

   // now proceed to write the "clipped" image to a file
   if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
      hr = pImageFactory->CreateStream(&pStream);
   }

   if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
      hr = pStream->InitializeFromFilename(MultiByteToUnicode(szNewFileName).c_str(), GENERIC_WRITE);
   }

   if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
      hr = pImageFactory->CreateEncoder(GUID_ContainerFormatJpeg, NULL, &pEncoder);
   }

   if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
      hr = pEncoder->Initialize(pStream, WICBitmapEncoderNoCache);
   }

   if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
      hr = pEncoder->CreateNewFrame(&pFrame, NULL);
   }

   if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
      hr = pFrame->Initialize(NULL);
   }

   if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
      hr = pFrame->SetSize((UINT)imageD->GetSize().width, (UINT)imageD->GetSize().height);
   }

   if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
      hr = pFrame->SetPixelFormat(&format);
   }

   if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
      hr = pFrame->WriteSource(pWICBitmap, NULL);
   }

   if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
      hr = pFrame->Commit();
   }

   if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
      hr = pEncoder->Commit();
   }
```

More info

```
      D2D1_POINT_2U topleft = D2D1::Point2U(0, 0);
   D2D1_RECT_U srcRect = D2D1::RectU(imageRect.left, imageRect.top, imageRect.right, imageRect.bottom);
   // get the "clipped" source
   hr = imageD->CopyFromBitmap(&topleft, imageS, &srcRect);

   if (hr != S_OK)
   {
   }

   UINT wD, hD;
   wD = (UINT)imageD->GetSize().width;
   hD = (UINT)imageD->GetSize().height;
```

The imageRect is correct LTRB = 0,0,320,240

but after the copy wD = 102 and hD = 76

Why?

Here is some more info

```
CComPtr<ID2D1Bitmap> imageD;
   D2D1_SIZE_U bitmapPixelSize = D2D1::SizeU(imageRect.Width(), imageRect.Height());

   // create destination image of "clipped" source image
   hr = pRenderTarget->CreateBitmap(bitmapPixelSize, D2D1::BitmapProperties(
      D2D1::PixelFormat(fmt.format, fmt.alphaMode),
      (float)resX, (float)resY), &imageD);

   UINT wD, hD;
   wD = (UINT)imageD->GetSize().width;
   hD = (UINT)imageD->GetSize().height;
```

The bitmapPixelSize is correct 320 x 240, resX and Y are 300

```
    format= DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM
    alphaMode   D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED
```

wD = 102 and hD = 76 - Why?

Latest code

```
IWICImagingFactory *pImageFactory = GfxAgent::WICImagingFactory::GetInstance().GetFactory();

   D2D1_SIZE_U sizeFrame = D2D1::SizeU(imageRect.Width(), imageRect.Height());

   CComPtr<IWICBitmap> pWICBitmap;
   hr = pImageFactory->CreateBitmap(imageRect.Width(), imageRect.Height(),
      GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA,
      WICBitmapCacheOnLoad,
      &pWICBitmap
      );

   // sanity check
   UINT wicW, wicH;
   pWICBitmap->GetSize(&wicW, &wicH);

   D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES rtProps = D2D1::RenderTargetProperties();
   rtProps.pixelFormat = D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED);
   rtProps.type = D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_DEFAULT;
   rtProps.usage = D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_USAGE_NONE;

   // define the render target
   CComPtr<ID2D1RenderTarget> pRenderTarget = 0;
   hr = m_pDirect2dFactory->CreateWicBitmapRenderTarget(pWICBitmap, rtProps, &pRenderTarget);

   CComPtr<ID2D1Bitmap> imageS;
   hr = GfxAgent::ImageUtilities::LoadImageFromFile(pRenderTarget, m_imgPath, 0, 0, 0, &imageS, &resX, &resY);

   if (hr != S_OK)
   {
   }

   // set new image resolution same as source
   pWICBitmap->SetResolution(resX, resY);

   // get format of image we just read
   D2D1_PIXEL_FORMAT fmt = imageS->GetPixelFormat();

   CComPtr<ID2D1Bitmap> imageD;
   D2D1_SIZE_U bitmapPixelSize = D2D1::SizeU(imageRect.Width(), imageRect.Height());

   // create destination image of "clipped" source image
   hr = pRenderTarget->CreateBitmap(bitmapPixelSize, D2D1::BitmapProperties(
      D2D1::PixelFormat(fmt.format, fmt.alphaMode),
      (float)resX, (float)resY), &imageD);

   D2D1_POINT_2U topleft = D2D1::Point2U(0, 0);
   D2D1_RECT_U srcRect = D2D1::RectU(imageRect.left, imageRect.top, imageRect.right, imageRect.bottom);
   // get the "clipped" source
   hr = imageD->CopyFromBitmap(&topleft, imageS, &srcRect);

   if (hr != S_OK)
   {
   }

   // just a sanity check (pixels NOT DIPS)
   D2D1_SIZE_U sourcePixelSize = imageS->GetPixelSize();
   D2D1_SIZE_U destPixelSize = imageD->GetPixelSize();

   CComPtr<IWICBitmapEncoder> pEncoder;
   CComPtr<IWICBitmapFrameEncode> pFrame;
   CComPtr<IWICStream> pStream;

   WICPixelFormatGUID format = GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA;

   // draw the "clipped" image into the render target (WIC image)
   if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
      pRenderTarget->BeginDraw();
      pRenderTarget->Clear();
      pRenderTarget->DrawBitmap(imageD);
      hr = pRenderTarget->EndDraw();
   }

   // now proceed to write the "clipped" image to a file
   if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
      hr = pImageFactory->CreateStream(&pStream);
   }

   if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
      hr = pStream->InitializeFromFilename(MultiByteToUnicode(szNewFileName).c_str(), GENERIC_WRITE);
   }

   if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
      hr = pImageFactory->CreateEncoder(GUID_ContainerFormatJpeg, NULL, &pEncoder);
   }

   if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
      hr = pEncoder->Initialize(pStream, WICBitmapEncoderNoCache);
   }

   if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
      hr = pEncoder->CreateNewFrame(&pFrame, NULL);
   }

   if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
      hr = pFrame->Initialize(NULL);
   }

   if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
      hr = pFrame->SetSize(destPixelSize.width, destPixelSize.height);
   }

   if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
      hr = pFrame->SetPixelFormat(&format);
   }

   if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
      hr = pFrame->WriteSource(pWICBitmap, NULL);
   }

   if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
      hr = pFrame->Commit();
   }

   if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
      hr = pEncoder->Commit();
   }
```

Comment: Telling us what programming language this is would help!

Comment: Windows 7 or 8.1, c++

Answer (score 1):

[`ID2D1Bitmap::GetSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371170%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) gets you DIPs:

> Returns the size, in device-independent pixels (DIPs), of the bitmap.
>
> A DIP is 1/96 of an inch. To retrieve the size in device pixels, use the ID2D1Bitmap::GetPixelSize method.

In your case the size is 320 px * 96 dpi/px / 300 dpi = 102.4 device-independent pixels. The same along Y axis.

Comment: OK, I'm going to review my code and the documentation again for those "fine" wordings. Thanks - I'll report back when I correct

Comment: Here are my changes which now yields a jpg file with the correct size (320x240) but the copied image looks like 102x76 in the upper left hand corner. Reading some of the API docs the size parameters specify width or height, or pixels, not very specific. Here is the updated code posted in the original post if I get this to work.

Comment: Presumably `imageS` and `imageD` are of different DPI. I see you are trying to change that with `SetResolution` call but it looks like it's late and has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing what the original image's resolution is when I create the render target from the WICBitmap I used the following properties

```
   D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES rtProps = D2D1::RenderTargetProperties();
   rtProps.pixelFormat = D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED);
   rtProps.type = D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_DEFAULT;
   rtProps.usage = D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_USAGE_NONE;
   rtProps.dpiX = (float)m_img.GetResolutionX();
   rtProps.dpiY = (float)m_img.GetResolutionY();
```

the key was using the resolution of the original image in the create, attempting to set them later did nothing. Roman gave me the "hint" - Thanks